# How to make titles of chapters in an edited volume?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, titles, combine

For an edited volume whose chapters live in separate files and which will probably have to be compiled separately, what is the best way to make the titles? Separate titlepages are not required, just chapter number (possibly), title and author should be printed on each chapter's first page.

I am using the `memoir` class, and the rich availability of chapter styles for it looks promising, but obviously `\chapter` doesn't have a built-in option for the author to be displayed, and does not have a `\thanks` command.

There are workarounds for both problems, of course. `\maketitle` on the other hand is the standard way in articles of printing title and author, and it sort of does what is needed, but I don't yet understand how to customise it, and it, as far as I understand, doesn't make a ToC entry (Which would become relevant only if I should manage to get a ToC automatically generated for the volume, which I doubt).

So, I somewhat tend to build the titling of the chapters around the `\chapter` command, but I'm not yet sure that that is actually the best route. I'd like to hear some wise thought on this and see some nice examples how others do this.

Comment: Maybe http://ctan.org/pkg/combine?

Comment: Also http://ctan.org/topic/subdocs.

Comment: @cfr, yes, I already had a first, unfortunately rather unsuccessfull, look at the combine package. It would probably need some time to fix things, but a more thorough inspection of it is definitely on my todo list. I remember it having serious problem with a chapter which has its own local ToC.

Comment: Is there any news here? The question does not really say what is needed. Where should stuff go? In what order? etc.